# How to get Jenkins environment variables in Extended Choice Parameter plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, extended-choice-parameter

I have to define a single select combo box where a list of available values is defined in a Jenkins environment variable (`Manage Jenkins → Configure System → Global properties → Environment variables`). How could I achieve that?

I tried to use `build` and `env` objects, but they are undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found how to do it:

```
import hudson.slaves.EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

Jenkins.get().globalNodeProperties.get(EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty).envVars['VARIABLE_NAME']
```

Comment: like EnvironmentVariablesNodeProperty, is there EnvironmentVariablesBuildProperty? I want to use some of the env variable which are build specific

Comment: This is a configuration of the Extended Choice Parameter which represents an input for job build parameter. The build does not exist yet, so you cannot access any build environment variables.